# Make a simple menu bar in Kivy (Python)

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy

I am currently learning how to use Kivy to make a desktop Python GUI.
I am trying to make a simple menu bar at the top of the application. This should look like something like that :
[image: menu bar]

I have tried to use the ActionBar as shown in the [showcase](http://kivy.org/docs/examples/gen__demo__showcase__main__py.html). So here is my code :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from kivy.app import App

class MenuApp(App):
    def button1(self):
        print("Button 1 triggered")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MenuApp().run()
```

And file menu.kv :

```
#:kivy 1.0.9

BoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"

    ActionBar:
        ActionView:
            ActionButton:
                text: "Button 1"
                on_release: app.button1()

    Button:
        text: "Nothing"
        background_color: 1, 1, 1, 0.6
        background_normal: ""
```

But I have the following error :

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /home/matthieu/.kivy/logs/kivy_15-06-29_19.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.9.0
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.4.0 (default, Jun 19 2015, 14:20:21) 
[GCC 4.8.2]
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 173 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_gif, img_sdl2, img_pil (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [OSC         ] using <multiprocessing> for socket
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2(['window_egl_rpi'] ignored)
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'3.0 Mesa 10.3.2'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'X.Org'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'Gallium 0.4 on AMD OLAND'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 3, 0
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'1.30'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <16>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
[INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress...
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "menuBar2/menuBar.py", line 14, in <module>
     MenuApp().run()
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/app.py", line 824, in run
     runTouchApp()
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/base.py", line 487, in runTouchApp
     EventLoop.window.mainloop()
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 539, in mainloop
     self._mainloop()
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 300, in _mainloop
     EventLoop.idle()
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/base.py", line 327, in idle
     Clock.tick()
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/clock.py", line 483, in tick
     self._process_events()
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/clock.py", line 615, in _process_events
     event.tick(self._last_tick, remove)
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/clock.py", line 374, in tick
     ret = callback(self._dt)
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/uix/boxlayout.py", line 174, in do_layout
     c.width = w
   File "properties.pyx", line 397, in kivy.properties.Property.__set__ (kivy/properties.c:4543)
   File "properties.pyx", line 429, in kivy.properties.Property.set (kivy/properties.c:5025)
   File "properties.pyx", line 484, in kivy.properties.Property.dispatch (kivy/properties.c:5641)
   File "_event.pyx", line 1168, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch (kivy/_event.c:11690)
   File "_event.pyx", line 1074, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch (kivy/_event.c:11029)
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/uix/actionbar.py", line 568, in on_width
     self._layout_all()
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/uix/actionbar.py", line 453, in _layout_all
     super_add(self.action_previous)
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/uix/boxlayout.py", line 210, in add_widget
     widget.bind(
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bind'
```

Does someone know what I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try it like this , i think it should work

```
ActionBar:
    ActionPrevious:
    ActionView:
        ActionButton:
            text: "Button 1"
            on_release: app.button1()
```

Comment: @Flns Thanks this made it work again. (But with the `ActionPrevious` inside `ActionView`). Does this means the previous button is necessary ? If so is there another way to simply do the bar ? I started something with buttons and drop-downs but I am struggling with the position of dropdown right now.